# browser page unexpectedly scrolls to topmost position after javascript button click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

How can I stop the browser page from scrolling to the topmost position within the browser after my slider button is clicked?  I had assumed the problem is with the javascript given that the undesirable and forced upward scrolling occurs after the button click event is triggered, but I'm not completely sure.  I've posted my code and markup so that this error can be reproduced and to simplify debugging I've combined the html, css and javascript in one file.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
 });

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});  

</script>
<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

nav { 
float: left;
background-color: #EEEFFF;
height: 1500px;
width: 100px;
}

html {
border-top: 5px solid #fff;
background: #58DDAF;
color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 160px;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
test
</nav>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next"></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"></a>
    <ul>
     <li>SLIDE 1</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
     <li>SLIDE 3</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `<a>` tags have the attribute `href="#"`, the default browser behaviour is to navigate to the URL `http://yoursite.com/your/page#`. This has the effect of the browser scrolling back up to the top of the page (because it looks for something with a blank `id`, doesn't find one, so just scrolls to the top of the page).

You can prevent this default browser behaviour using one of two techniques in your Javascript click handler function:

1. `return false;` from the handler function; or
2. Call the `.preventDefault()` method on the `event` argument your function gets passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the click of the link

```
$('a.control_prev').click(function (e) {
    moveLeft();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

(do it for the other also)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you have an href="#", so I changed the a tags to a button tags, and change them in jquery, and in the css, i added:border:solid transparent;, to make it look similar to when it was with a tags, here's the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
 });

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('button.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('button.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});  

</script>
<style>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

nav { 
float: left;
background-color: #EEEFFF;
height: 1500px;
width: 100px;
}

html {
border-top: 5px solid #fff;
background: #58DDAF;
color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

button.control_prev, button.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
border:solid transparent;
}

button.control_prev:hover, button.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

button.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

button.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 160px;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
test
</nav>
<div id="slider">
  <button class="control_next"></button>
  <button class="control_prev"></button>
    <ul>
     <li>SLIDE 1</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
     <li>SLIDE 3</li>
     <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```